# Where is composition tab in QGIS Composer to change page size?

Tags: qgis, qgis-print-layouts

I am trying to change the page size in the QGIS 3.0 Composer but I am not able to see the Composition tab.  I have right clicked an empty space in the toolbar but did not see anything about composition.  I am using Windows 7.  I tried looking at the QGIS docs but they are still in testing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's sort of hidden, but still there. In QGIS 3.0, you can now have multiple pages in a single composer screen, and each page can be adjusted on its own. The pages are hidden from the **Items** panel, but all you need to do is right-click on any page and select **Page properties**. The settings you're used to seeing will pop into the **Item properties** tab:

[image: page properties]