# Export Layout problem in QGIS 3.4 and Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, qgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

I try to export the layout into A0 size- but all size options bigger than A3 are blocked. I working with QGIS 3.4, windows 10. In QGIS 2.18 there no problem export layout to any size. But when i work with other PC with windows 7- there no any size export problems in QGIS 3.4 & QGIS 2.18

i red this, but didn't found solution to my problem:

- https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18557
- [QGIS window size problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292902/qgis-window-size-problem)
- [Where is the composition tab in QGIS 3.0 Composer, so I can change page size?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273152/where-is-the-composition-tab-in-qgis-3-0-composer-so-i-can-change-page-size)

Comment: It could be problem with windows platform 32 or 64-bit. Try qgis with 32bit

Comment: but my system is 64bit

Comment: Try with 32bit qgis